# Playing a sound instantly using Clips

Tags: java, javasound

I have been learning how to play sounds for a while now, and I have a nice way of doing so, but there is one problem. I try to play the sound, but it doesn't play immediately after the method is run.

Here's my code:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            File audioFile = new File(soundMap.get(key));
            try {
                AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
                AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
                DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
                Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                AudioListener listener = new AudioListener();
                audioClip.addLineListener(listener);
                audioClip.open(audioStream);
                audioClip.start();
                listener.waitUntilDone();
                audioClip.close();

            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
                System.out.println("The specified audio file is not supported.");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                System.out.println("Audio line for playing back is unavailable.");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error playing the audio file.");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

All the AudioListener class is, is something that allows the thread to wait until the sound is done.

On a side note, I will be using this for games, so playing a specific sound multiple times is bound to happen, so if there is a way to work around that too, that would help a lot.

Comment: it takes 1-3 seconds to load the file etc - so you can preload all these - if that is what you are asking

Comment: But if I play the sound multiple times, it goes back to the beginning instead

Comment: *"it goes back to the beginning instead"* Why is that a problem? Note also the `Clip` methods like [`Clip.setMicrosecondPosition(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#setMicrosecondPosition-long-) ..

Answer (score 0):

The comments pretty much cover things, but I will summarize a few points.

1) With Clip, you pre-load and hold the objects in memory. Do not combine the open() and start() method in series. The start() method will not run until the entire file is loaded into memory.

2) You can replay a Clip from the beginning by using the setMicrosecondPosition(0) or setFramePosition(0) prior to running the start() method.

3) As long as the game is running, the Clip will run in its own thread in the background. There is no need to "wait until done". The audio runs on a daemon thread, concurrently with other activity. Unlike regular threads, daemon threads will allow themselves to be shut down if there is nothing else running. But while the program is running, while there are graphics on the screen, animation, etc., the sound should run fine.

I recommend making a "SoundHandler" class, and making instance variables (Clips) for your different game sounds, and opening them in the Constructor. You can also make methods to play the different sounds. This should be good enough for a first pass on a simple game. Something along the lines as what follows (exception handling omitted):

```
class SoundHandler

    Clip gunshot;
    Clip explosion;

    public SoundHandler()
    {
        gunshot = loadGunshot();
        explosion = loadExplosion();
    }

    private Clip loadGunshot()
    {
        // code to make and open a Clip
    }

    public void playGunshot()
    {
        gunshot.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
        gunshot.start();
    }

    // et cetera
}
```

In your main game thread, you instantiate a copy of SoundHandler, and reference in the game loop when you need to make a sound.

```
soundHandler.playGunshot();
```